# Switch between Jquery AJAX and PHP with target="_blank"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a search result displayed - in this there is an anchor tag like below.

```
<div class="addfriend">
    <a href="add_friend.php?from=kpkdhar22&id=2" id="2" target="_blank" onclick="addfriend(1, 2)">Add as friend</a>
</div>
```

I was doing this because, I want to keep my search result. I dont want to do `POST`-`REDIRECT`-`GET` method. I was using AJAX to update friends nesting DB table. If I prevent default action on anchor tag, the link is being opened in the same page and redirected to `add_friend.php?from=kpkdhar22&id=2` , DB is updated and when back is pressed search result page is giving error message and search is gone. I want to keep `target="_blank"` because in case JS is not enabled in browser, it will do in php.

Can I execute the JS function other than anchor tag and still have a new tab.

My AJAX code is like this :

```
function addfriend(fid, uid) {
    // uid --  person sending friends request
    // fid --  person receiving friends request

    var id = '#' + uid;
    $("id").parent().empty().addClass("friend").removeClass("addfriend").html("<span>Request sent</span>");

    var userid   = uid;
    var friendid = fid;
    var status   = 'N';

    var dataString = 'userid=' + uid + '&friendid=' + fid + '&status=' + status;

    $.ajax({
        type   : "POST",
        url    : "js/add_friend.php",
        data   : dataString,
        cache  : true,
        success: function (html) {
            var id = '#' + uid;   // is this ok as selector
            $("id").parent().empty().addClass("friend").removeClass("addfriend").html("<span>Request sent</span>");
        },
        error  : function () {
            $("#errors").html('');
            $("#errors").html('Failed to send your request.');
        }
    });
}
```

When the function `addfriend(1,2)` is executed, a new tab is opened and in add_friend.php a JS alert message is displayed and I am closing that tab immediately. But AJAX success function is not executed, so I added the same before AJAX call, but that is also not worked.

console message -- XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/bp1/js/add_friend1.php".

Please suggest me some process, or steps where am I going wrong.

Regards,
Poorna.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your link stop acting as such. Your AJAX call inside the `addfriend()` function complicates this a little, but not too much. First of all, change the "onclick" attribute of your link to

```
onclick="return addfriend(1, 2)"
```

i.e. add the `return` statement, and add this to the very end of your `addfriend()` JS function (after your AJAX call):

```
return false;
```

This will trick DOM into thinking that you did click on your link, but for some reason it didn't go well, and the browser should not follow the "href" URL.